# Understanding python class attributes

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am very new to programming and started learning python. Might look very stupid question, so please pardon my ignorance.
Consider the following snippet of code :

```
class Test1:
    bar = 10    
    def display(self,foo):
        self.foo=foo
        print "foo : ",self.foo #80
    def display1(self):
        print "bar: ", self.bar #10
        print "again foo: ", self.foo #80

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test1 = Test1()
    test1.display(80)
    test1.display1()
    print test1.bar #10
    print test1.foo #80
```

I want to understand what is the difference between using foo and bar (wrt to where we have defined them) as in scope wise they are equally accessible at all places compared to each other and only difference is that one is inside function and other is inside Class but they both are still "instance" variable.
So which is good practice?

Also, if I slightly modify display function as below :

```
    def display(self,foo):
        self.foo=foo
        foo = foo
        print "self.foo : ",self.foo 
        print "foo : ",foo
```

Can someone please explain how python sees this, as in what difference/significance this `self` keyword is bringing in between two `foo`.

Comment: No, `bar` is *not* an instance variable. The two are very different which is why it's not about "good practice". It's about what is appropriate for your situation, because they serve different purposes.

Comment: Also `self.bar` works because the name `bar` is first searched in the namespace of the instance, and then in the class. The fact that `self.bar` works does not *always* mean that `bar` is an instance variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bar` is a class attribute. Since classes in Python are objects, they too can have attributes. `bar` just happens to live on that `Test` object, not an instance thereof.

Because of the way Python resolves attribute lookups, it looks like `test1` has a `bar` attribute, but it doesn't.

`foo` on the other hand lives on the instance `test1` after calling `display(80)`. This means that different instances of `Test`can have different values in their respective `foo` attributes.

Of course, you could use class variables as some kind of "shared default value", which you can then "override" with an instance attribute, but that might get confusing.

**Second question**

```
def display(self,foo):
    self.foo=foo
    foo = foo
    print "self.foo : ",self.foo 
    print "foo : ",foo
```

Let's just get a detail out of the way: `self` is not a keyword, it's just convention to call the first argument "self", you could also call it "this" or "that" or "bar" if you liked, but I wouldn't recommend that.

Python will pass the object, on which the method was called as the first argument.

```
def display(self,foo):
```

This foo is the name of the first parameter of the display instance-function.

```
    self.foo=foo
```

This sets the attribute with the name "foo" of the instance, on which you called `display()` to the value, which you passed as first argument. Using your example `test1.display(80)`, `self` will be `test1`, `foo` is `80` and `test1.foo` will thus be set to `80`.

```
    foo = foo
```

This does nothing at all. It references the first parameter `foo`.

The next two lines again reference the instance variable `foo` and the first parameter `foo`.

Answer (score 4):

`bar` is a class attribute and `foo` is an instance attribute. The main difference is that `bar` will be available to all class instances while `foo` will be available to an instance only if you call display on that instance

```
>>> ins1 = Test1()
```

`ins1.bar` works fine because it is a class attribute and is shared by all instances.

```
>>> ins1.bar
10
```

But you can't access foo directly here as it is not defined yet:

```
>>> ins1.foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-62-9495b4da308f>", line 1, in <module>
    ins1.foo
AttributeError: Test1 instance has no attribute 'foo'

>>> ins1.display(12)
foo :  12
>>> ins1.foo
12
```

If you want to initialize some instance attributes when the instance is created then place them inside the `__init__` method.

```
class A(object):
    bar =  10
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo   #this gets initialized when the instance is created
    def func(self, x):
        self.spam = x    #this will be available only when you call func() on the instance
...         
>>> a = A(10)
>>> a.bar
10
>>> a.foo
10
>>> a.spam
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-85-3b4ed07da1b4>", line 1, in <module>
    a.spam
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'spam'

>>> a.func(2)
>>> a.spam
2
```

Comment: I think the *main* difference is that a class attribute is "shared", not that it's available to all instances.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't like defining instance variables inside of methods other than `__init__` or as class variables like `bar` in your example above.

Again, personally, I like to see every member of my class by looking at the top.  Whether it is a class variable that you use as an instance variable (something I don't usually do) or an instance variable defined in `__init__`, it is easy to tell what is and isn't defined in a class by inspecting the first section of the class definition.

If you won't need to access a variable as a class member (ie. you are only defining it there to avoid writing `self.variable = val` in the `__init__` method, then I would steer clear of it.  If you might need to access it as a class variable, then doing what you are with `bar` is ok in my book.

This would be my preferred way of writing you class.

```
class Test1:

    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = None
        self.bar = 10

    def display(self,foo):
        self.foo=foo
        print "foo : ",self.foo #80

    def display1(self):
        print "bar: ", self.bar #10
        print "again foo: ", self.foo #80
```